# When does the increment expression execute

Tags: c#, for-loop, increment

Please tell me why the value of sum after this C# for loop executes is 20 and not 30:

```
for (int i = 2; i < 10; i += 2)
{
    sum += i;
}
```

It seems to me that at the end of the first iteration, i would be 2 and sum 2, at the end of the 2nd i would be 4 and sum 6, then 6 and 12, then 8 and 20. Then, when the loop starts into the 5th iteration, i would still be less than 10 at 8, so i would increment to 10 and sum would be 20 + 10 = 30. Then the next time around i = 10, so execution stops. But the answer is 20. Why doesn't the loop go into that 5th iteration? Please be gentle with me.

Thank you very much for enlightenment.

Comment: You would need i <=10 to get what you expect

Comment: Good opportunity to learn how the debugger works :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it ask us to ececute the provided code to get the answer. That is where a compiler and debugger are for.

Comment: @rene a look into the standard at http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf about "12.3.3.9 For statements" should be equally effective, althought, maybe still off-topic

Comment: Your belief is that the increment happens after the check. This belief is incorrect. The increment happens before the check. I encourage you to read the specification to answer questions like this.

Answer (score 12):

The loop is executed `4 times`, when `i` is `2, 4, 6,` and `8`
Total is 20.

No mistery to solve here. When `i` reaches `10` the evaluation of the for condition `i < 10` is   false and thus, 10 is never added to `sum` variable

To complete the answer the logic of [`for` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) is simple:

- Set the initial value for the variable that controls the exit expression `(i=2)`
- Evaluate the exit expression, if true enter the for body, if false exit `(i < 10)`
- Execute the for body `{ ... whatever... }`
- Increment the variable for the steps required `(i+=2)`
- Restart from the evaluation of the exit expression

Answer (score 2):

```
Loop 0 : i = 2, sum = 0 + 2 = 2
Loop 1 : i = 2 + 2 = 4, sum = 2 + 4 = 6
Loop 2 : i = 4 + 2 = 6, sum = 6 + 6 = 12
Loop 3 : i = 6 + 2 = 8, sum = 12 + 8 = 20
Loop 4 : i = 8 + 2 = 10, for loop stops.

Result: sum = 20
```

The for loop you wrote is the same as:

```
int i = 2;
while(true)
{
  if (i < 10)
  {
      sum += i;
  }
  else break;

  i += 2;
}
```

so `i` is incremented and then evaluated, if it is not meeting the condition the loop will be breaked.

Answer (score 2):

In `for (a;b;c) d;` the evaluation order is a,b,d,(c,b,d) where (c,b,d) repeats (if `b` is ever `false`, the loop breaks right there). You seemed to think the order was (b,c,d). Stepping through the code in the debugger will make this clear.

In your case, this means that after `i == 8`, `i` is incremented to `10` and then `i < 10` is tested; since it is `false`, the loop breaks before adding `10` to `sum`. This is a more easy and natural way for a `for` loop to work, especially in cases like looping through an array:

```
// actual; i will have values from 0 (inclusive) to array.Length (exclusive)
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
// if it worked how you assumed, it'd be
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
// but the last time you go through the loop, i < array.Length - 1 isn't true
```

Answer (score 1):

As others already pointed out, the answer is that the loop doesn't enter the 5th iteration because the [stop-]condition in your example is '<' (smaller than operator) and not '<=' (smaller than or equal) so that the number of loops, which could be defined as '2n < 10' resolves to 'n < 5' where 4 is the closest valid match for n.

You may find [the MS docs about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) helpful. Here's an excerpt:

> for (initializer; condition; iterator)
>
> ```
>   body
> ```
>
> The initializer section sets the initial conditions. The statements in this section run only once, before you enter the loop. The section can contain only one of the following two options.
>
> - The declaration and initialization of a local loop variable, as the first example shows (int i = 1). The variable is local to the loop and can't be accessed from outside the loop.
> - Zero or more statement expressons [...]
>
> The condition section contains a boolean expression that’s evaluated to determine whether the loop should exit or should run again.
>
> The iterator section defines what happens after each iteration of the body of the loop. The iterator section contains zero or more [...] statement expressions, separated by commas [...]

As a sidenote, it may be worth mentioning that the operators for relational testing like '<' and '<=' could be overloaded for user defined types and make the loop harder to read, but since you're using int as the control variables type (which is not a user defined type), this cannot be the case for your example.

The [C# language specification - ECMA-334](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) shows a very clear definition in "12.3.3.9 For statements" which also explaines that the for loop

```
for (int i = 2; i < 10; i += 2)
{
  sum += i;
}
```

can be translated into a while loop

```
int sum = 0;
int i = 2;
while (i < 10)
{
    sum += i;
    i += 2;
}
```

which makes the order of instructions more obvious.

Using [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the output of the two loops is identical besides some NOP instructions. Here's a little annotated version:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Testloop() cil managed
{
  // Code size       27 (0x1b)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] int32 sum,      <-- this is location 0 --> 1. int sum = 0;
                [1] int32 i,        <-- this is location 1 --> 2. int i = 2;
                [2] bool CS$4$0000) <-- this is location 2 --> 3. unnamed temporary result storage for the i < 10 comparison
  IL_0000:  nop --> no operation is the machine code equivalent of a space character and can be ignored
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0          --> 1. int sum = 0;
  IL_0002:  stloc.0           --> 1.
  IL_0003:  ldc.i4.2          --> 2. int i = 2;
  IL_0004:  stloc.1           --> 2.
  IL_0005:  br.s  IL_0011     --> branch to target IL_0011, which is a "goto" and jumps over the conditional check and iterator code which starts at IL_0007
  IL_0007:  nop --> no operation is the machine code equivalent of a space character and can be ignored
  IL_0008:  ldloc.0           --> 5. sum += i
  IL_0009:  ldloc.1           --> 5.
  IL_000a:  add               --> 5.
  IL_000b:  stloc.0           --> 5.
  IL_000c:  nop --> no operation is the machine code equivalent of a space character and can be ignored
  IL_000d:  ldloc.1           --> 6. i += 2
  IL_000e:  ldc.i4.2          --> 6.
  IL_000f:  add               --> 6.
  IL_0010:  stloc.1           --> 6.
  IL_0011:  ldloc.1           --> 3. i < 10
  IL_0012:  ldc.i4.s   10     --> 3.
  IL_0014:  clt               --> 3.
  IL_0016:  stloc.2           --> 4. continue until ( 3. ) is true (meaning, i >= 10) by jumping back to the start at IL_0007
  IL_0017:  ldloc.2           --> 4. 
  IL_0018:  brtrue.s  IL_0007 --> 4.
  IL_001a:  ret --> the closing bracket of the method Testloop()
} // end of method Program::Testloop
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of how `for` operates.  I'll turn the loop into the statements that execute, so you get a better idea:

```
int i = 2;
if (i < 10) {
    sum += i; // sum = 2
}
i += 2; // i = 4
if (i < 10) {
    sum += i; // sum = 6
}
i += 2; // i = 6
if (i < 10) {
    sum += i; // sum = 12
}
i += 2; // i = 8
if (i < 10) {
    sum += i; // sum = 20
}
i += 2; // i = 10
if (i < 10) {
    // nothing, since 10 <= 10, but *not* 10 < 10
}
```